# SecTTerBot: Twitter bot, which tweets newly answered Information Security questions

Tags: app, twitter

#### About

[SecTTerBot](https://twitter.com/SecTTerBot) is simple script which main purpose is to check if there are any new questions with provided any answers on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com).

When new questions appears, and someone reply to them SecTTer will grab it, and post in as tweet on his profile

#### Why?

I like very much to read questions on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com), but unfortunatly, when I'm using my mobile phone I have to jump between Twitter application and web browser to have update. With this tool we can notice when someone answer newly created question.

#### Usage

You can follow [SecTTerBot](https://twitter.com/SecTTerBot) on Twitter

#### License

Free-as-beer

#### Comments

- Application is now in beta version, when I finish coding I will post source code on Github.
- Feel free to do a feature request.
- You can contact me via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TenSts)